# Removing a file from an array of files on click with react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I am trying to create a function that allows me to remove a file from an array of files using the index,  onclick.

`**input:** files to upload stored in the state using hooks`

`**output:** files to upload stored in the state minus the removed file`

here is what I have so far I am wondering if I am on the right track or is there a better way to go about doing this.

```
// remove document from uploadFiles array
      const removeFile = index => {
        // take an array of files and select a file at a given index
        // remove a file at a selected index
        // reassign all the indexs
        const selectFile = index;
        setFilesToUpload(filesToUpload.filter(file => file.selectFile[index] !== selectFile));
      };

      return (
        <div className={uploadStyles.fileContainer} key={uuid()}>
          <div className={uploadStyles.fileTitle}>
            <p>Document {(index += 1)}</p>
            <SquareButton
              label={"remove file"}
              icon={"x-mark"}
              small={true}
              name={file.selectFile}
              onClick={() => removeFile(index)}
            />
          </div>
          <p className={uploadStyles.filePath}>{file.path}</p>
          <p className={uploadStyles.fileTS}>
            {file.type}
            {"   "}|{"   "}
            {formatBytes()}
          </p>
          <div className={uploadStyles.progressLine} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use `splice`.

Before:

`setFilesToUpload(filesToUpload.filter(file => file.selectFile[index] !== selectFile));`

After:

`setFilesToUpload(filesToUpload.splice(index, 1)));`

The second parameter represents the amount of elements to be deleted

> [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
>
> > The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place

Comment: Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: it works however if i try to remove 1 file from the array if there are more than one it removes every index down to that file as well

Answer (score 1):

In the filter method the 2nd argument is `index`, make use of this to simplify.

```
const removeFile = (index) => {
  setFilesToUpload(filesToUpload.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
};
```

Comment: this solution works however how do i handle cases where this is only one item in the array that i need to filter out.